# Stable, unchanged numeration of rows in Vuetify Data Table

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I'm learning Vue and Vuetify at the moment and I've faced the problem of indexing rows in data tables.

The only way I can assign the number of a row is relying on `indexOf` comparing to the raw array of data. 
But the problem in my case is that when I sort data in the table index breaks accordingly. 
I would like to have it stable and when you sort data it recalculates.

Is there any way to achieve it in Vue? 
In Angular it's much easier with tables. There is a build-in functionality

Or maybe you know how to reach the filtered or sorted data (array) where Vue holds it.

```
  <v-data-table
          :headers="headers"
          :items="orders"
          class="elevation-2 mt-4"
          :loading="loading"
          loading-text="Loading... Please wait"
        >
          <template v-slot:item.index="{ item }">
           {{ orders.indexOf(item) + 1}}
          </template>
  </v-data-table>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is a built-in `item.index` value that can be displayed via `headers` object. This index doesn't break if you sort data using VDataTable UI.

P. S. I'm not sure if I understood the question, so if my comment doesn't help, please let me know and clarify the question a bit :)

Comment: @elushnikova yes, that’s what I needed - an unbreakable index throughout the data table. How can I declare that index value into my table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I've managed to get it working (thanks to @elushnikova) is like this:

```
        <v-data-table
          :headers="headers"
          :items="orders"
          class="elevation-2 mt-4"
          :loading="loading"
          loading-text="Loading... Please wait"
        >
          <template v-slot:item="{item, index}">
            <tr>
              <td>{{index + 1}}</td>
              <td>{{item.client_name}}</td>
              <td>{{item.client_id}}</td>
              <td>{{item.order_total}}</td>
            </tr>
          </template>
        </v-data-table>
```

It doesn't break on sorting. But I believe later I'll have another problem with it when I have pagination. 
But let's solve problems as they come :)

Answer (score 1):

I found this  in this [link](https://dev-qa.com/783985/how-to-add-row-number-in-v-datatable)

```
 <template #item.index="{ item }">
{{ protocolData.indexOf(item) }}
 </template>
```

and its worked for me.

Comment: Thanks, I’ll try it out later

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved in vuetify using item. slot, you need to pass a header for index along with other headers (eg. SNO).
now just use this in v-data-table.

```
<template v-slot:item.SNO = "{ index }">
    {{ index + 1 }}
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Closest way to get the result is by using a computed property as show in codepen
https://codepen.io/manojkmishra/pen/OJyYzVo

Template Part:

```
<div id="app">
<v-app>
  <h3>Orders</h3>
  <v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="ordersWithIndex"/>
</v-app>
</div>
```

Script Part:

```
new Vue({
el: '#app',
vuetify: new Vuetify(),
data() {
return {
  headers: [{ text: 'Num', value: 'index' },
    { text: 'OrderName',  value: 'Name'   },
    {  text: 'OrderValue',   value: 'value'   }
  ],
  orders: [ {Name: 'order1', value: 100   },
            { Name: 'order2', value: 200 },
           { Name: 'order3', value: 300 },
           { Name: 'order4', value: 400 }
          ],
}
},
computed: {
ordersWithIndex() 
{  return this.orders.map(
    (items, index) => ({
      ...items,
      index: index + 1
    }))
}
}
})
```

Comment: This same result can be achieved without a computed function. You can get it working with indexOf comparing to the raw data array. If you sort now the table in your example the index of rows will break - at first it’s 1,2,3,... after sorting it gets somewhat like 3,2,1,...

Comment: here is the working codepen with indexOf solution - https://codepen.io/manojkmishra/pen/MWadQwm.  unique value column should be used inside indexOf(item.name) else it will show same id for rows having same names.

Comment: Of course below solution will work but it has few limitations as its not using full features of v-data-table. In this case one needs to explicitly give all the column names even if they are present in headers. Further issue will be there if we want to assign dynamic value columns which are not present in array.

Comment: agree, it’s not a perfect  solution and doesn’t seem elegant nor comfortable to code and arrange the column order all the time. I’m saying nothing about maintaining it. But for now I have only this one and I either use this one and focus on the code learning the framework or start making a brand new UI element which fits me well. Angular seems better with row indices so far but simplicity of Vue attracts me a lot

Comment: It doesn't answer the question. The index must be fixed, It desnt have to change on sorting