# Vuetify v-data table get Index

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, v-data-table

Hey there I am new to vue js and vuetify.In my editProductSave I want to pass another variable which is the index of the row in the table. This is my current code and how would i achieve that? The table is plotted using the vuetify v-data-table

Whole code

```
 <template>
      <v-card>
        <v-data-table
          :headers="tableFields"
          :items="programs"
          :items-per-page="5">
                <template v-slot:[`item._id.$oid`]="{ item }">
                  {{item._id.$oid}}
                </template>
                <template v-slot:[`item.tags`]="props">
                <v-edit-dialog
                  :return-value.sync="props.item.tags"
                  large
                  persistent
                  @save="editProductSave(props.item)">
                  <div>{{props.item.tags.length === 0 ? '' : props.item.tags}}</div>
                  <template v-slot:input>
                    <div class="mt-1 text-h2">
                      Update Tag
                    </div>
                    <v-text-field
                      v-model="props.item.tags"
                      label="Edit"
                      single-line
                      counter
                      autofocus
                    ></v-text-field>
                  </template>
                </v-edit-dialog>
                </template>

<script>
 import tdmApi from "../services/api/Database";

  export default {
    props: ["DatabaseList"],
    computed: {
      totalRows() {
        return this.programs.length;
      },
    },
    created () {
      this.viewTdmDatabase();
    },
    data () {
      return {
        tableFields: [
          {text:'ID',value:'_id.$oid'},
          {text:'Tag',value:'tags'},
        ],
        programs: [],
      }
    },
</script>
```

Comment: Where is the row index?

Comment: which slot are you using ? please share the whole code

Comment: @BeshambherChaukhwan I am new to vue js and i am plotting the table using v-data-table

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim added the whole code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<template v-slot:item.tags="{item,index}">
         {{index}} //Output index
</template>
```

The code above should work, make sure to cover it with object.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
     <template v-slot:[`item.tags`]="{props, index}">
                <v-edit-dialog
                  :return-value.sync="props.item.tags"
                  large persistent
                  @save="editProductSave(props.item, index)">
                // ...
                </v-edit-dialog>
    </template>
```

And in script the method would be

```
methods: {
     editProductSave(item, index) {
        // ...
     }
}
```

Comment: It is not rendering my data in the table

Comment: `<template v-slot:[`item.tags`]="props,index">`  Plots my table but the index value is undefined

Comment: See if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62031595/stable-unchanged-numeration-of-rows-in-vuetify-data-table

Answer (score 0):

It seems that vuetify does not have in [the v-data-table api the index field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46380574/how-to-display-the-index-of-an-array-using-the-vuetify-data-table), so in order to get it you can change the structure of the v-data-table.

This is an example of how to get the index of each row.

https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/whatever/vuetify+v-data-table+get+row+index

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add the index to the programs in a computed property and import it in the data table like so:

*template*

```html
...
<v-data-table
      :headers="tableFields"
      :items="programsComputed"
...
```

*script*

```js
  export default {
    ...
    computed: {
      totalRows() {
        return this.programs.length;
      },
      programsComputed () {
        return this.programs.map((program, index) => {
          program.index = index;
          return program;
        })
      }
    },
    ...
    data () {
      return {
        tableFields: [
          {text:'ID',value:'_id.$oid'},
          {text:'Tag',value:'tags'},
        ],
        programs: [],
      }
    },
```

In your `editProductSave(item)` you would just have to call `item.index`